# Why isn't my keyboard appearing?

Tags: iphone, ios4, keyboard, iphone-softkeyboard

I have an application that allows the user to edit multiple text fields and views. Rather than mess around raising each view to the top when the keyboard is active, I decided to instead make one textView for editing and hide/show it when input is needed, then transfer the data when it is done. To move focus to the new textView, I call its becomeFirstResponder method, and lo and behold, the cursor goes to the right place. However if I use this method, the iPhone keyboard does not appear. I have no idea why. Can anyone explain, and tell me how to make the keyboard appear? All the other questions I've looked at seem to indicate that setting becomeFirstResponder for a textView ought to make the keyboard come up.

-Ash

Comment: Do you have a bluetooth keyboard hooked up?

Comment: No, I'm running in the simulator.

Comment: I'm pretty curious to see this interface. This sounds like a really novel approach.

Comment: In the end I abandoned it as an unnecessary embuggerance upon my coding time and went back to simply shifting the data fields up out of the way of the keyboard :) The code can be made to work I'm sure, but I was probably implementing it in the wrong place: textViewDidBeginEditing. In retrospect, it might have worked if I'd placed it somewhere like textViewWillBeginEditing (assuming such a method exists within the protocol) since it wouldn't be conflicting with the textView's own wishes. I might try this again sometime, but now my code is working I don't want to mess with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `Hardware -> Simulate Hardware Keyboard` enabled?

Comment: Yep.
However, I think I found out what the problem was. I was attempting to set the delegate within a routine that somehow denied the setting of a delegate, namely textViewDidBeginEditing

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this whole thing programatically or using Interface Builder as well?
If so are the IB connections setup right?

Comment: Yep, otherwise it wouldn't have performed the other tasks within the same code block. However, I think I found out what the problem was. I was attempting to set the delegate within a routine that somehow denied the setting of a delegate, namely textViewDidBeginEditing